# Xml To Json Conversion with same value needed in Json Without Exponential Form

Tags: json, xml, output

I convert Xml Data to Json Data and my input in xml file or text file is:-

```
    //**xml input:- <data>34123456.00</data>**
    String jsonFileName = "src\\main\\resources\\Light.json";
    try {
        File xmlFile = new File("src\\main\\resources\\output.txt");
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int ptr;
        while ((ptr = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            builder.append((char) ptr);
        }

        String xml = builder.toString();
        JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
        System.out.print(jsonObj);
        FileWriter fileWriter =
                new FileWriter(jsonFileName);

        // Always wrap FileWriter in BufferedWriter.
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =
                new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        bufferedWriter.write(jsonObj.toString(PRETTY_FACTOR));
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
                "Error writing to file '"
                        + jsonFileName + "'");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } /* json output is :- {"data":3.4123456E7}
         I want Output as :-  {"data":34123456.00} */
```

but i dont want exponential form in json format i want complete number so how i do this in Java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml,true);
```

write above  line instead of

```
JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
```

this solves my problem.